# when try to define a functional component in react with styled-components using typescript get error of "No overload matches this call."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-type-checking-question-0b42t

Code

```
type BadgeTypes = {
  success: string;
  secondary: string;
  alert: string;
  text: string;
};

type Theme = {
  fonts?: object;
  borderRadius: string;
  primary?: object;
  accent?: object;
  action?: object;
  stories?: object;
  checkbox?: object;
  badge: BadgeTypes;
  button?: object;
  page?: object;
  states?: object;
  modal?: object;
};
interface Props {
  theme: Theme;
  large: boolean;
  type: keyof BadgeTypes;
}
const StyledBadge = styled.span<Props>`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: ${(props: Props): string => props.theme.borderRadius};
  text-align: center;
  color: ${(props: Props): string => props.theme.badge.text};
  font-size: ${(props: Props): string => (props.large ? `1.4rem` : `1rem`)};
  padding: ${(props: Props): string =>
    props.large ? `0 .8rem` : `0.2rem 0.6rem 0.3rem 0.6rem`};
  background: ${(props: Props): string => props.theme.badge[props.type]};
`;
interface BadgeProps {
  children: React.ReactChildren;
  // any other props that come into the component
}

const Badge = ({
  children,
  ...props
//problem likely the line below
}: BadgeProps): React.FunctionComponentElement<BadgeProps> => (
  <StyledBadge {...props}>{children}</StyledBadge>
);
```

Error is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 253 more ... | "is"> & { ...; } & Props, "slot" | ... 258 more ... | "large"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 257 more ... | "large"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactChildren; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 253 more ... | "is"> & { ...; } & Props, "slot" | ... 258 more ... | "large"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 257 more ... | "large">': type, large
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"span", any, Props, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"span", any, Props, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactChildren; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 253 more ... | "is"> & { ...; } & Props, "slot" | ... 258 more ... | "large"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 257 more ... | "large">': type, largets(2769)
```

I am aware it is likely a result of a wrong function return type I put there after `BadgeProps):` But I can't find a proper type to put in after a few googling.

Answer (score 0):

It's more about your `BadgeProps`, they are in no way related to `Props`. And since `StyledBadge` has props of type `Props`, TypeScript will yell!

To fix that I made a [small code sandbox with necessary fixes](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-type-checking-question-m3f67?file=/src/index.tsx:995-1009).

I also made small changes to the way you declare your `Badge` component :)

Comment: The solution will give error on the line in your example says `Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.`

error below

`````
const StyledBadge: StyledComponent<"span", any, Props, never>
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<BadgeProps>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren<BadgeProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)
`````

Comment: but when I replaced FC with `FunctionComponentElement` which I original wrote, it works fine